# Image properties when using linear layout in android

Tags: android, image, position, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Hi Im trying to create a simple android page with text at the top of the page and an image below it. Ive tried using both linear and relative layouts but I just cannot get the image to display below the text. Either the image is next to the text either on the left or off the screen to the right, or when using a relative layout the image takes up the entire screen.

Is there any image properties that will allow to accomplish this, I do not want to use the deprecated absolute layout if possible.

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gripbckgrnd" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="211dp"
        android:src="@drawable/grip1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="356dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/griptext"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `LinearLayout`, you can specify the orientation-attribute like so:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

(The default is horizontal, which causes your problems)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you not specify your UI components even in dp, if you don't need to.  Because screens can have minor variations in their dimensions (for example, some tablets are 1280x800 and some are 1280x720), it's better to use specifications that  can stretch and give a bit, like match_parent, wrap_content, and layout_weight.  Here's a sample layout that uses some of these attributes.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:src="@drawable/my_drawable"
    android:contentDescription="@string/describe_drawable"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, your example puts the image on top. :-)